# Failed to deserialize Avro record : Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

I am trying to read from Kafka with Avro format using Pyflink

My Program is this :

```
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.datastream.formats.avro import AvroRowDeserializationSchema,AvroSchema
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment

avro_schema = """{"type":"record","name":"NewName","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long"},{"name":"UserId","type":["null","long"],"default":null},{"name":"fffId","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"gtbId","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"TimeofTrans","type":["null",{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}],"default":null},{"name":"CheckType","type":["null","string"],"default":null}],"connect.name":"NewName"}"""

# initial setup
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

env.add_jars("file:///Desktop/Projects/streaming/flink_py_test/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar")
env.add_jars("file:///Desktop/Projects/streaming/flink_py_test/flink-sql-avro-1.16.0.jar")

# getting the table env for SQL
deserialization_schema = AvroRowDeserializationSchema(
    avro_schema_string=avro_schema
)

kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    topics='NewTopicName',
    deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
    properties={'bootstrap.servers': '172.10.10.10:9092,172.20.10.10:9092,172.30.10.10:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group_1'}
)
kafka_consumer.set_start_from_latest()
source = env.add_source(kafka_consumer).print()

env.execute()
```

It is giving **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException**. I have tried using the KafkaConsumer class and FlinkKafkaConsumer class to create a consumer and tried to specify the deserialization using the AvroDeserializationSchema. None of them worked.

```
    org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:268)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1277)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
        at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
        at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:256)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:247)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:240)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:738)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:715)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:477)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDeserializationSchema.java:167)
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDeserializationSchema.java:85)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:82)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:58)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:179)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:142)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:826)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:333)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 25 out of bounds for length 2
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:283)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:142)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDeserializationSchema.java:164)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: Were you able to get to the root of it?
I am currently facing this too. The only difference is it Is not the Row but the default Confluent Avro deserializer given by flink that i am using.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. 

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem in Flink SQL. The underlying issue for me was that a field in my schema needed to be designated `NOT NULL` but was not.

In your case, I imagine one of your fields has

```
"type":["null","<type>"]
```

but should have

```
"type":"<type>"
```

Let's take another look at your error message:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 25 out of bounds for length 2

Avro stores nullable fields as union types. The 25 refers to the numeric value or the length of the string it's trying to parse. The 2 refers to the length of the nullable value container that it is expecting.